# Especificação? Qual melhor termo?

Tags: terminologia, convenções-de-nome

Em programação é usado o termo **especificação** para incluir características que um sistema tem, porém preciso saber o termo para quando for para um site, por exemplo: O site pode ter até 5 páginas, inclui formulário de contato etc e links de redes sociais.

Qual termo categórico para este assunto? Especificação está certo para falar do que inclui num site sem ser um sistema?

Comment: Eu descreveria como **recursos** talvez...

Comment: Meio estranho para site, para sistema combina bem

Comment: Isso parece ser levantamento de **requisitos**.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, sem problemas.

O termo "especificações" geralmente é uma redução do termo "especificações de requisitos".

E especificações de requisitos tem a ver com descrição de atividades que determinarão o objetivo do sistema/projeto e todas as restrições associadas a ele.

Especificar que "O site pode ter até 5 páginas, inclui formulário de contato etc e links de redes sociais." é uma forma de descrever e restringir o que o projeto pode ter.

Eu seria mais "específico" e tiraria o "etc", fazendo uma lista assim:

1. Ter 5 páginas
2. Ter 1 formulário para contato
3. Ter links para as redes sociais X, Y e Z